# How to transform more arrays in one string? (Array to String)

Tags: php, arrays, string

How an inside function `preg_replace_callback_array` transform array to string?

```
Array
(
    [0] => string
)
Array
(
    [0] => string
)
Array
(
    [0] => string
)

string(6) "string"
string(6) "string"
string(6) "string"
```

I want to have:

```
string(18) "stringstringstring"
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a PHP function called implode that should do the trick:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = [
    ["string"],
    ["string"],
    ["string"]
 ];

$strs = [];

array_map(function($x) use (&$strs) {
    foreach($x as $v) $strs[] = $v;
}, $data);

var_dump($strs);
```